# Fixing mysql error #1064

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migrate

I have a query which works fine in MSSQL but giving #1064 error in MYSQL. Please help me to identify the error? Thanks in advance

```
UPDATE setup_business_rule  
SET  
BR_NAME='SEND_EMAIL_AFTER_TICKET_OPEN edit',  
BR_DESC='Send notification email when new ticket was created.', 
BR_CATEGORY='Desktop', 
STATUS='False', 
SMS='False', 
EMAIL='True', 
CONDITION=' [TICKETSTATUS] [=] [STATUSOPEN]',
OCCURS_CREATE='True', 
OCCURS_UPDATE='True', 
TARGET_SMS='', 
ACTION_ON='Notification', 
TARGET_EMAIL=' [techsupport@macrokiosk.com] [Contact Email]', 
TARGET_MESSAGE='message', 
ESCALATION_TYPE='0000000', 
ESCALATION_TABLE='', 
ESCALATION_COLUMN='', 
ESCALATION_VALUE='', 
OCCURS_FORM='HD', 
OCCURS_FIELD='0000000', 
TARGET_SUBJECT='[TICKETDESCRIPTION] (CID:[TICKETNO])' , 
ACTION_GROUP_ID = '0000000',  
IS_WORKING_HOUR = 0,  
IS_BASED_DURATION = 0,  
MINUTES_DURATION = ''  
WHERE BR_ID='000001' 
AND SEG_ID ='0001'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only issue I see is in below line where `condition` is reserve word and should be escaped using backtique

```
`CONDITION` =' [TICKETSTATUS] [=] [STATUSOPEN]'
```

So your entire `UPDATE` statement should look like

```
UPDATE setup_business_rule  
SET  
BR_NAME='SEND_EMAIL_AFTER_TICKET_OPEN edit',  
BR_DESC='Send notification email when new ticket was created.', 
BR_CATEGORY='Desktop', 
STATUS='False', 
SMS='False', 
EMAIL='True', 
`CONDITION`=' [TICKETSTATUS] [=] [STATUSOPEN]', <-- Here
OCCURS_CREATE='True', 
OCCURS_UPDATE='True', 
TARGET_SMS='', 
ACTION_ON='Notification', 
TARGET_EMAIL=' [techsupport@macrokiosk.com] [Contact Email]', 
TARGET_MESSAGE='message', 
ESCALATION_TYPE='0000000', 
ESCALATION_TABLE='', 
ESCALATION_COLUMN='', 
ESCALATION_VALUE='', 
OCCURS_FORM='HD', 
OCCURS_FIELD='0000000', 
TARGET_SUBJECT='[TICKETDESCRIPTION] (CID:[TICKETNO])' , 
ACTION_GROUP_ID = '0000000',  
IS_WORKING_HOUR = 0,  
IS_BASED_DURATION = 0,  
MINUTES_DURATION = ''  
WHERE BR_ID='000001' 
AND SEG_ID ='0001'
```

Comment: +1 sharp eye..Can you add link for reserved keyword mysql..it will helpful

Comment: @NagarajS, Thanks, about link to documentation .. that's left as homework to question owner.